# Binding ListView to an array of objects, where each object has an array of points

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, binding, view

I have an array of objects, and each object contains an array of points.  I want to bind these arrays to a list-view, but the problem is with the point array.  I want to dynamically expand each row to the size of the point array...
Any Suggestions?